# ModuleNotFoundError when trying import class from module

Tags: python, import, module, importerror, uvicorn

I have the following project structure:

```
└──my_project
   └──package
      └──subpackage
         ├──containers.py
         ├──dbase.py
         └──main.py
```

In "dbase.py" methods for interacting with database, in "main.py" API methods.
And following imports in apps:

```
#package/main
from subpackage.dbase import module1
from subpackage.containers import module2, module3
```

```
#package/dbase
from subpackage.containers import module2
```

I try run server from "my_project" (the same problem, when run from "subpackage"):

```
uvicorn package.subpackage.main:app
```

And get following error:

```
    from subpackage.containers import module2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subpackage'
```

or

```
from subpackage.dbase import module1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subpackage'
```

But when I run pytest there are no problems with imports.
How I can solve it?

Comment: try `from my_project.package.subpackage.dbase import module1`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in project structure. I change it to:

```
└──my_project
   └──package
      ├──subpackage
      |  ├──containers.py
      |  └──dbase.py
      └──main.py
```

And there are no problems with imports